# IntelliJ: Ruby plugin is shutting down IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

A plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby is incompatible with the current edition of IntelliJ IDEA. IntelliJ IDEA will now shutdown.

No way around it, I can't use settings to disable the plugin, I can't do anything. Why is this the behavior of the plugin? I don't need Ruby.

Comment: At least on OSX, it was possible for me to bring up the Preferences dialog and disable the Ruby plugin, while that message box was shown. Then restart Intellij and you should be good again.

Comment: On Linux, where the dialogs are modal, you can edit the file `.IntelliJIdea15/config/disabled_plugins.txt`and add the crashing plugin (for me it was Pythonid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be already fixed... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148075

Comment: The new version isn't released yet but it's coming today :) I fixed by installing old IntelliJ, disabling the plugin and then updating.